# Docker communication between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to create two containers and connect from one to another and I fail to do so.
My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  my_network:

services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: sleep infinity
    networks:
      - my_network
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 80:80
    networks:
      - my_network
```

To test connection I run `echo "" > /dev/tcp/0.0.0.0/80` on host machine and it goes fine;
Then I do the same inside the second container `test`;
There I get

```
echo "" > /dev/tcp/0.0.0.0/80
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/0.0.0.0/80: Connection refused
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Your `test` container isn't running anything on port 80. Your `nginx` container is. You probably want `echo "" > /dev/tcp/nginx/80`.

Comment: @larsks I get this: `bash: nginx: Name or service not known`

Comment: Are you running your command on the *host* or inside container *test*?

Comment: @larsks my actual container names were different from ones that I posted, so I messed them up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect from one container to the other using the service name, in your case `test` or `nginx`. For example in the `nginx` container you could run:

```
$ echo "" > /dev/tcp/test/<port>
```

You don't even need to expose the port in the `docker-compose.yml`.

If you want to use a different hostname to connect to a container you can use [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases)

Comment: I get this: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test`

Comment: edit: updated the command to better reflect your question. Are you sure both containers are in the same network and running?

Comment: still not working: `bash: test: Name or service not known`

Comment: @Rugnar Try `ping test`. Do you get a response?

Comment: @leopal I run ping when inside the `test` container: `ping: test: Name or service not known`, same for nginx `ping: nginx: Name or service not known`

Comment: @leopal at frist I messed up with container names. That worked, thanks