# how to dockerize a spring microservices app that uses Eureka and Cloud config

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, microservices

i'm working in this spring microservices application, and everything works fine untill i want to dockerize the microservices. Having a little knowledge about docker i'm struggling to make it work, Here's what i've done till now:

**1.Config server**
this server is a centralized server that contains common configurations of other services and also special configurations for each microservice.

This is the config service configuration

```
spring.profiles.active=native
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=classpath:/common-config
spring.application.name=config-server
#the password which apps will use to access its configurations
spring.security.user.password=1234
```

then i added a foler in src/main/resources called common-config which contains each service configs:

1. discover-service.yml

this is configuration for eureka server

```
server:
  port: 8762
```

Then in the root of the config-server, i add 2 files Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="sanchi.goyal.sg@gmail.com"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8888 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8888

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=./target/*.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
  config-server:
    image: config-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=
         -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discover-service:8762/eureka
    ports:
      - 8888:8888  
  discover-service:
    image: discover-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8762:8762
    depends_on:
      - config-server
restart: on-failure
```

Now in the discover-service application, ive added Dockerfile in root directory as follow:

```
    # Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="sanchi.goyal.sg@gmail.com"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8888 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8762

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=./target/*.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

and in src/main/resources, i have added the file bootstrap.yml as follow:

```
#This file is the entrypoint for spring to know where to look for the configuration file and hold the initial configuration

spring:
  application:
    name: discover-service #name of the application
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888 #where the config-service is running
      fail-fast: true #the service will not run if it can't reach the config-service
      password: 1234 #password of the config-service
      username: user #username of the config-service

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true #when the application registers with eureka, it uses its IP address rather than its hostname
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false #tells the built-in eureka client to not register itself with eureka, because we should act as a server
    fetchRegistry: false
```

Now here's the problem, before starting dockerize the two apps, i build a jar file and docker jar file for each app, so for the config-server app i create the 2 JARs with no problems, but for the second app, in order to create the 2 JARs,i have to keep the below property in bootstrap.yml so it knows where the config server.

```
uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Now moving to docker, when i run the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

the first app works, but the second app says:

```
Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/discover-service/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

can any one please help me with this !

here's my github repository https://github.com/MoroccanGeek/UnitedRemote-BackendChanllenge
I didn't commit the changes described in this question. You will find multiple services, but if i can run the 2 described apps in docker i can do it with the other ones

**EDIT**
I've managed to start my applications by changing docker-compose.yml to this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  config-server:
    image: config-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=
         -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discover-service:8762/eureka
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
  discover-service:
    image: discover-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8762:8762
    depends_on:
      - config-server
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  host:
```

but something weird is happening, when i want for example go to discover-service application (which is an eureka server), it doesnt work, but when i go to another website on the same Tab and go back it shows what is expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker connet between two containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967498/docker-connet-between-two-containers)

Comment: @leopal no it didn't work